# how do I reincorporate a fork of my repo on github

Tags: git, github

I have a small github project which has been forked by another user. I like the changes he's made. What's the best way to merge them back into my original repo?

Everything I find online deals with going the *other* way - updating your fork from the original repo. I want to do the opposite and pull back in changes made by another coder.

Is asking her to submit a pull-request the only way?

Answer (score 1):

Add that repo as a new remote to your local repo, start pulling changes from the other repo on your branches and push them into *your* original repo.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is through GitHub pull requests. Note that anyone can make a pull request between a fork and an original repository as long as they can view both repositories (you don't need write access to send pull requests).

1. Visit the fork on GitHub.
2. If the branch you want to merge in isn't `master`, click on the branch switcher to select the branch.
3. Click `New pull request` next to the branch switcher.
4. Optionally write a title and description for future reference.
5. Create and merge the pull request, which will update your original repository with the fork's changes.